# Why are there duplicate files when extracting tar.gz archive

Tags: shell, tar, 7zip

I have a strange problem with tar.gz archives that I do not understand.

I create the archive on a linux server with `tar -czf`

When I extract them on a windows machine using `7z x`, I always get notifications that some (not all) files already exist. (They are extracted to an empty directory.)

The files it wants to replace have todays date, the ones already there have the original (modified on) date they had on the server.

Since I want to preserve the original timestamps I can use the `-aos` option for 7z, but I would like to understand why this is happening and make sure that I have an identical mirror of the files on the server after unpacking locally.

Comment: Are you sure there are no symlinks in your tar-gz archive?

Comment: There are no symlinks in the original directory structure on the server so I am assuming there are none in the archive... how do I check if there are are symlinks in the archive?

Comment: Because I'm not sure how 7z behaves when extracting a symlink on a Windows file-system that potentially does not support them.

Comment: there seems to be one additional folder containing exactly 100 files
(the archive has one more folder and 100 more files than there are left after extraction)
I checked for symlinks on the server using: ls -lR /path/to/folder | grep ^l and there are none

Comment: It would be extremely useful if you created a minimal `tar.gz` archive and post a link to it here, so that we can unpack it by ourselves

Answer (score 6):

:D The problem is a derelict duplicate directory that exists both as uppercase and lowercase on the Linux server - which of course can only be one directory when extracted on the Windows System ( \Mydir\ and \mydir\ ) problem solved. :)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your comment about Windows file-system support pointed me in the right direction and I remembered that I had a similar problem many many years ago. :P